# Tmux: Scroll buffer not working on MSYS2/MINGW64 (Git for Windows SDK)

Tags: windows, tmux, git, mingw, msys

I installed the [Git for Windows SDK](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra) on Windows 11 to have the `pacman` package installer available to install `tmux`.

A lot of stuff works like it used to be on other platforms, but scrolling back using <kbd>PREFIX</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> does not really work.

I can see how the terminal enters scroll mode (yellow counter in the top right), but I can't move at all and its frozen at `0/XX`. All I can do is exit scrolling with `C-c`.

How can I fix this issue?

My `.tmux.conf`:

```
# prefix
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-t
bind C-t send-prefix

# behavior
set -g escape-time 10 # see https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/353#issuecomment-294570322
set -g repeat-time 550 # allows holding down array keys for continuous strokes on MacOS

# theme
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g status-bg color234
set -g status-fg white
set-window-option -g window-status-current-style bg=color233
bind § command-prompt -p "(set status-bg)" "set status-bg %1"

# rename
bind $ command-prompt "rename-session '%%'"
bind , command-prompt "rename-window '%%'"

# persistent cwd
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind '"' split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"

# reload config
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using and what does `echo $TERM` show when you're in the terminal outside of tmux?

Comment: @bk2204 I'm using the default Git Bash (initiated by `C:\git-sdk-64\git-bash.exe`), which is recommend to use for Git for Windows SDK. Outside of `tmux` the output of `echo $TERM` is `xterm-256color`.